# How can I output a dynamically created image directly within a HTML page?

Tags: php, http-headers, gd

I have a HTML page. On this page I want to display a dynamically created PNG image **without saving it to a file first**.

When I simply try to create the image within the page, of course I get an error stating that headers where already sent.

---

Sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>An Image</h1>
<?php

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$white = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = ImageColorAllocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 50, 50, $white);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 50, 50, 100, $black);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 50, 0, 100, 50, $black);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 50, 50, 100, 100, $white);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is buffering the image in a variable and then encode the img as base64:

```
ob_start(); 
imagepng($im); 
$img_content = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 

$dataUri = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($img_content);
echo '<img src="' . $dataUri . '">';
```